# How to Remove duplicates from an array of objects using ES6?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering what the best method would be to merge 2 array of objects `itemsA` and `itemsB`. The data once merged should be in `mergedList`.

Criteria:

1. Items with `source='STAPLE'` should not repeat in merged array.
2. Items with any other source may repeat. For exampele an item `name: 'Ball'` by `source: 'USER'` may exist twice.

`itemsA` has 6 items, `itemsB` has 7 items and `mergedList` should have 11 items

```
let itemsA = [
{name: 'Milk', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Bread', source: 'AD'},
{name: 'Egg', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Ball', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Pasta', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Coke', source: 'AD'}];
let itemsB = [
{name: 'Milk', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Bread', source: 'AD'},
{name: 'Egg', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Ball', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Mango', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Pasta', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Coke', source: 'USER'}]
```

`mergedList` should equal to

```
let mergedList = [
{name: 'Milk', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Bread', source: 'AD'},
{name: 'Egg', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Ball', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Pasta', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Coke', source: 'AD'}] 
{name: 'Milk', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Bread', source: 'AD'},
{name: 'Ball', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Mango', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Coke', source: 'USER'}]   ];
```

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that your data doesn't really seem to make sense, at least not from the logic that you're suggesting. You say you want to allow everything with only "user" to repeat, but in your merged list you have things that are not "user" repeating. That being said, what have you tried?

Comment: @zfrisch Yes sorry I wrote the criteria wrong, I was just trying to give an example. You're right, Any source other than STAPLE may repeat.

Comment: @zfrisch No, the question states that STAPLE can't repeat, but the others can. the confusion comes from the fact that only one example, user, was given.

Comment: concat then reduce. simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function merge(itemsA, itemsB) {
  let merged = [];
  itemsA.concat(itemsB).reduce((stapleSet, obj) => (obj.source != "STAPLE") ?
  (merged.push(obj), stapleSet) : 
  (stapleSet.has(obj.name) || merged.push(obj), 
  stapleSet.add(obj.name), stapleSet), new Set());

  return merged;
}
```

- get two arrays.
- create a merged array to push objects to.
- concatenate the two item arrays together.
- reduce the concatenated array - if the object source is staple and not in `stapleSet` add the name of the object to `stapleSet` -- Set objects only allow one of each entry -- then push object to `merged` array. Otherwise push object to he `merged` array.
- return the merged array from the function.

```js
let itemsA = [
{name: 'Milk', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Bread', source: 'AD'},
{name: 'Egg', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Ball', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Pasta', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Coke', source: 'AD'}];
let itemsB = [
{name: 'Milk', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Bread', source: 'AD'},
{name: 'Egg', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Ball', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Mango', source: 'USER'},
{name: 'Pasta', source: 'STAPLE'},
{name: 'Coke', source: 'USER'}];

    function merge(itemsA, itemsB) {
      let merged = [];
      itemsA.concat(itemsB).reduce((stapleSet, obj) => (obj.source != "STAPLE") ?
      (merged.push(obj), stapleSet) : 
      (stapleSet.has(obj.name) || merged.push(obj), 
      stapleSet.add(obj.name), stapleSet), new Set());

      return merged;
    }
    console.log( merge(itemsA, itemsB) );
```

**Edit**: If-Else formatting for OP

```
function merge(itemsA, itemsB) {
  let merged = [];
  itemsA.concat(itemsB).reduce((stapleSet, obj) => {
    if (obj.source != "STAPLE") {
      merged.push(obj);
      return stapleSet;
    } else {
      if (stapleSet.has(obj.name)) {
        return stapleSet;
      } else {
        merged.push(obj);
        stapleSet.add(obj.name);
        return stapleSet;
      }
    }
  }, new Set());
  return merged;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, how would this be written in an if-else block?

Comment: @aps5842 what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the current answer works but it's using the ternary operator, I am wondering if the same can be written using `if(){}else{}` statements

Comment: @aps5842 anything that is a ternary or a short-circuit can be rewritten as an if else statement. I added to my answer.